Discrete Math Help: $\lnot p \rightarrow (p \rightarrow q) \equiv T$
First week in discrete Math and my professor only gave 2 examples. Really need some help if I am doing this right. If you also have extra exercise problems with answers I can practice with please link me.
¬p → (p → q) ≡ T
¬¬ p v (p -> q) Disjunctive form
p v (p-> q) Double Negation
p v (¬p v q) Disjunctive form
(p v ¬ p) v q Associative Laws
T v q Law of excluded Middle
q v T Commutative Laws
T Domination Laws

Looks right to me.

Using Mathjax, the commands you want are \lor, \land, \lnot, \rightarrow, and \equiv.

@RobertShore \to is more convenient than \rightarrow

And @Mittens you want \neg rather than \neq. (An unsurprisingly common typo.)

$p\rightarrow q$ is false if and only if  is true and  is false. in such case, $\neg p\rightarrow(p\rightarrow q)$ yields a true value ("false implies false is true). In any case where. In any case where $p\rightarrow q$ is true, $\neg p \rightarrow(p\rightarrow q)$ yields a True value.

Recall that $p\to q$ does not mean that $p$ causes $q$, or that $q$ is always true when $p$ is true. In classical propositional logic, it simply excludes the possibility that both $p$ is true and $q$ is false. $~~p\to q ~~\equiv ~~ \neg (p \land \neg q)$. Example: "It is raining implies it is cloudy" simply rules out the possibility that it is both raining and not cloudy (present tense).
